# Single Sign on Authentication with CAS

Tags: php, .net, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I am trying to implement single sign-on authentication between two of my applications one in PHP and the other in .NET. The PHP site currently makes a Web Service call to a .NET Web method to authenticate the user. Both the .NET site and the PHP site use the same database. I was inclined to think I could implement a single sign on mechanism where if the user logs in to the php site he is automatically authenticated to the .net site as well. CAS authentication seems to be somewhat relevant to my case. But I am not sure where it exactly fits between my applications. So let me break it down into distinct steps please let me know if I am right?

1. User visits www.myphpsite.com/login
2. He supplies the username and password and clicks on the login button.
3. A web service call is then made to the .NET web method hosted in the same server as my .NET application www.myDotNetApp.com
4. The Web service uses the database to authenticate the user.
5. Somewhere here CAS has to fit in and has to ensure that I am authenticated for both  www..com and www.myDotNetApp.com. In addition to doing this it has to set some session variables for the www..com site for the user to be able to view the different pages in the site.
6. Then the Web method has to redirect the user to the homepage in the www.myphpsite.com.
7. Now if the user clicks the link to www.myDotNetApp.com from  www.myphpsite.com he must be taken to his profile page in www.myDotNetApp.com because he is already authenticated.

Now, is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose is possible but I would suggest doing a little reading about how CAS works, the [CAS Protocol](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol) is a good resource.

What CAS provides is an authentication provider trusted by each of your websites. It is an additional hosted website / service along side your other websites wanting to use CAS to provide authentication.

Based on the information you provided in your example, here is how it would mostly likely play out:

1. User visits the PHP website `www.myphpsite.com/login`, recognizing the user is not yet authenticated the PHP website redirects the user to your CAS website.
2. The CAS website also does not recognize the user as authenticated and so presents the user with a login screen. The user enters their credentials which CAS verifies against the database and then redirects the user back to the PHP website.
3. The PHP website receives a service-ticket from CAS via URL parameter which it verifies with CAS making a back-end web-service call. Having received a confirmation from CAS that the service ticket was valid PHP then logs the user in using its built-in authentication procedure (i.e. instead of validating against the database the PHP website now validates with CAS to assert that a user is authentic).
4. At this point if the user attempts to access the .NET website `www.myDotNetApp.com` it would not be able to recognize the user as authenticated using its built-in authentication procedure and so it would redirect the user to the CAS website.
5. However, the CAS website would already recognize the user as authenticated. Instead of prompting the user to login, CAS would automatically redirect the user back to the .NET website providing a service-ticket as a URL parameter. The .NET website would then make a back-end web-service call to CAS verifying the service-ticket and log the user in using its built-in authentication procedure.

In summary, CAS provides a single place for users to authenticate. Other websites can then direct needs for authentication to CAS where CAS either asks the user to login or recognizes the user as already logged and notifies the website.

Comment: I believe the step4 doesn't again redirect to the CAS website. The first time the user successfully authenticates with CAS, a Ticket Granting Ticket (TGT) cookie is stored on users' browser which helps in bypassing the step of redirecting to the identity provider website. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @quirkystack, that is not correct. CAS does set a cookie, but due to cross domain restrictions it is not accessible to other sites. Therefore if a site needs to authenticate a user it redirects them to CAS. If CAS has recently authenticated the user it will see the cookie and immediately redirect the user back to the original website, often quickly enough to be unnoticed. When CAS redirects back to the original site it passes a temporary ticket (its only verifiable for 15 seconds) that the original site can verify via a backend call to CAS. Then the original site can set its own cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Think of CAS as being the HUB and your apps as being spokes in the hub & spoke model. A lot is based on implementation, but here's the general process.

When a users hits a protected area of your php app they will be redirected to CAS. They will authenticate against CAS which has been setup against your database. After successful authentication, they are routed back to your application with a token that gets verified and they are signed in. If the app is implemented correctly, then they end up back on the same page they were attempting to navigate to.

When they hit a link that sends them to your .net app, they will go over like normal. If the page requires authentication, then they are routed to CAS which already knows them and passes them back to the app with a token that gets verified and then get in, and most likely never realized they hit the CAS application.

Just in case it is pertinent, let's assume that the PHP app needs to call the .net app as the user, not just linking to a page, but needs to get .net content as the user him or herself... CAS also supports proxying, so the php application can impersonate the user and call .net directly.

Check out the CAS [architecture](http://www.jasig.org/cas/cas2-architecture) and the [protocol](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol) for more details.